# ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined - requireJS, r.js optimizer and localStorage

Tags: local-storage, requirejs, r.js

I'm trying to optimize my requireJS JavaScript app with r.js. Unfortunately it stops when it rans over the function "localStorage" (the browser-builtin localStorage-function).

The error message:

`ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`

The function where the error occures:

```
function getFromLocalStorage()
{
    return localStorage.getItem('foo') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo')) : {};
}
```

How to fix this kind of error? Is is possible to use localStore within the r.js optimizer?

More information:

The build script:

```
({
    appDir: "../",
    baseUrl: "js/",
    dir: "./build",
    mainConfigFile: "app.js",
    paths: {
        jQuery: "empty:"
    },
    name: "app",
    findNestesDependencies: true
})
```

Application structure:

```
/
---> /js (where app.js lies)
     ---> /app (here lies the file with the localStore-call)
     ---> /lib
```

Comment: Did you end up making any progress on this?

Comment: Not really - It seems that a reqiureJS plugin inside a requireJS module cause the problem. I switched to UglifyJS which basically does the same. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have a typo in your code above.

I didn't want to just edit your code, but I assume that:

```
 return localStorage.getItemfootv') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo')) : {};
```

Is supposed to be:

```
return localStorage.getItem('foo') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo')) : {};
```

With that change, I copied your code into a project of mine and it ran through the optimizer just fine.  What version are you using?  I tried with the latest version, 2.1.1.

If it's not an issue with the optimizer version you're using, I would try changing references of `localStorage` to `window.localStorage` and see if that make a difference.

Comment: Thank you, this was just a typo, this typo wasn't in the original code. I'm using version 2.1.1 either and tried to use window.localStorage - unsuccessfully, now 'window' is not defined.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what to make of that, but that at least indicates that it's not a problem with using localStorage, but rather with the optimization process.  Some quick googling turned up this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/requirejs/Zt9FOu74NqA/utcTxVn78YIJ.  Check the command you're invoking the optimizer with and make sure it's correct.